# iPhone app sound recognition?

Tags: iphone, audio, sound-recognition

I'm trying to get an app to record microphone input, and respond to certain sounds.
These sounds would be pre-recorded and played on a different device-- like website or TV.

So I'm guessing it'd be a matter of comparing the audio data.
Any idea about a good place to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording sound should be easy. Check the [Speak Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) code sample from apple. For comparing two sound files, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735018/compare-sounds-inside-of-the-app).